# Interval kind of help in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, intervals, pixel

Let me just get right to it.

How can I make it so that it will add a sprite to the screen every (let's say) 20 pixels? So as to create a line? I put interval in the title because I want there to be a sprite added every 20 pixels during the distance of two points. So if there are 2 points, and 200 pixels between them, 10 sprites would be put between them. Ask me if you require further clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, here's how I would do this:

You have your two endpoints P1 and P2. 
You can find any arbitrary point along the line created by them with the general equations:

```
x = P1.x + blend * (P2.x - P1.x);
y = P1.y + blend * (P2.y - P1.y);
```

Where blend is the percent between the two points.

So find what percentage 20 pixels is between the two by getting the distance between the points and dividing 20 by it. So by your example, 200 pixels between the two points, 20 pixels is 10%.

Then simply loop through creating new sprites while incrementing blend until it reaches 100%.

Comment: You need to find the distance between P1 and P2. If you're using CGPoints, then you can just call ccpDistance(P1,P2). If not, just Google distance formula to figure it out.

Then, you divide 20 by that distance--this gives you what percent 20 pixels is. So for example, if the distance between two points is 200 pixels, 20/200 = 0.10 = 10%. Starting at zero, you increment blend by this percentage (ie blend+= 0.10f), creating a new sprite at each new point, until blend reaches 100%.